# statistics.query.timeline[] has 4 sections while my BigQ SQL has 9 Stages (S00 to S09)

Tags: google-bigquery

statistics.query.timeline[] is giving me 4 sections in JSON response but my Query execution plan shows 9 stages. What do these 4 section in timeline correspond to ?

Comment: what are the 4 sections and what are the 9 sections? Please add a little more detail so we can help you

Comment: I am not able to paste JSON output here as it is too long but in my json response : 1) I have 4 sections under timeline block   2) 9 stages under stages  under Queryplan(that i can see from GUI Editor as well S00 to S09). As @Elliott mentioned in another comment that those are 4 snapshots under timeline block. i will look further details for snapshots

Answer (score 0):

The timeline has four snapshots that were taken during execution. Stages are potentially executed in an overlapping manner; there is no guarantee that they will be executed serially or that you will see a snapshot in which a particular stage is partially complete. See also the [query plan explanation documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation).

Comment: Thanks  @elliott !  SO is it correct to say that last snapshot under timeline is the most correct if i need to find total slots used(completedunits) in a query ?

Comment: The statistics has *slot milliseconds* used. Think of it like CPU time; you don't "use a CPU", rather, you use *time* on a CPU.